AppState Event Notifier.AppState Change += OnAuthStateChanged; not working unity
I am implementing AppOpen ad in my unity project for android devices and I'm getting AndroidJavaException. this error casused by AppState Event Notifier.AppState Change += OnAuthStateChanged;
See the image of error.
I'm using Unity 2022.3.44f1, Google Mobile Ads Plugin(Version 9.2.0) and Google Mobile Ads Android SDK 23.2.0.
